# allowing just friends to comments in their profile page

Tags: php, mysql

i have a profile page that contain a comment system and i just allow the owner of the profile to write their comments  now i want to allow friends also to write how to do that ???

in the members table i have a friend_array field that contain the ids  of users that are friend with this user

the friend request system include ajax and jquery

## code.php

```
$blab_form="";
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
  if($_SESSION['user_id']==$id)
  {
    $blab_form='
    '.$blab_output_msg.'<br />
                <div style="background-color:#D2F0D3;border:#999 1px solid; padding:8px;">
                <form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_form">
                      <textarea name="blab_field" cols="" rows="4"  style="width:100%;">
                      </textarea><br />
                      (220 Char Max)
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Blab"/>
                </form></div>';
        //$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM blabing WHERE u_id ='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

## friend_request_system

```
<?php 
//****************friend request system********************//
// for securing the request with  and encryption to be  more secure.
if(isset($_SESSION['wpit']))
{
    $_SESSION['wipt'];
}
$theRundomNum = rand(99999999999999,9999999999999);
$_SESSION['wipt'] = base64_encode($theRundomNum);

//*********for distinguich the users*************//
//if member is a viewer
$friendLink = "";
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&$_SESSION['user_id']!=$id)
{
     //for quering friend array  for the viewer if he is not the owner 
     $sqlArray = mysql_query("SELECT  friend_array FROM members WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlArray))
     {
         $iFriendArray = $row['friend_array'];
     }
     $iFriendArray = explode("," , $iFriendArray);
     if(in_array($id, $iFriendArray))
     {
         $friendLink = '<a href="#" onclick = "return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'remove_friend\');">Remove Friend</a>';
     }
     else
     {
         $friendLink = '<a href="#" onclick = "return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'add_friend\');">Add as Friend</a>';
     }
    $interactionBox='<div class="interactionLinksDiv">
     '.$friendLink.' 
    </div>';
}
//if member is the profile ower
else
{
    $interactionBox = '<div class="interactionLinksDiv">
     <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'friend_requests\');">Freind Request List</a> </div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: more code ?? as what ??

Comment: like the `friend_array` ..,

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Comment: i have updated my answer to use your friend array.

Answer (score 1):

`if($_SESSION['user_id']==$id)` is specific to the blog owner, right? So you make this conditional check if the session id is in an array of acceptable id's. Something like this:

```
// assuming you already populated the $iFriendArray as outlined in your question
$iFriendArray[] = $id; // add blog owner to the friend array


if(in_array($_SESSION['user_id'], $iFriendArray))
{
    // can comment
}
```

This has been updated to use the friend array as updated in your question.

Any questions feel free to ask and I may update.